# Can we put a formula in the "value_if_true" field in an IF Function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a situation where i need to put a formula in the `Value_if_true` and `Value_if_false` fields in an `IF` function but it does not seems to be working. It just keeps displaying my formula as is in the cell. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for asking a question.

Comment: Can you paste the formula as part of the question?   That way we don't have to guess.  We can see if you're using " where you should not be.

Comment: Hi, Here is the formula: =IF(I5=0,"(12-BC5)*BE5 + BH5","BF5")

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please update your question with your additional information.  It's your question, you can correct it to be complete.

Answer (score 3):

This has wrong " characters

```
=IF(I5=0,"(12-BC5)*BE5 + BH5","BF5")
```

`"(12-BC5)*BE5 + BH5"` is a string.  Not a formula.  Use this.

```
=IF(I5=0,(12-BC5)*BE5 + BH5,BF5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Um...
Just remove all inner quotes from your formula.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:
you have to remove " character and separate the arguments of the IF function with a ;

So the solution is: =IF(I5=0; (12-BC5)*BE5 + BH5; BF5)

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make value_if_true and value_if_false column to input true value/ false value formula
2. Choose true value.
3. Use If formula use the value_if_true and value_if_false column.